# Duplicate ID issue in case of simultaneous request to controller method

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to generate `JobListingId` by attaching the Company ID to it.

In our company table, we have `JobCount` column which stores how many jobs we have against a company.

So whenever we create a new job posting, we update this `JobCount` in our Company table as well.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> SaveJobListing(JobListingModel model)
 {
      // Fetching the Company ID
        var company = await _context.Company.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CompanyID == model.CompanyId);
        var jobListingDomainModel =  new JobListing();  
        jobListingDomainModel.JobListingId = companyID + "," + (company.JobCount + 1);
        company.JobCount = (company.JobCount + 1);
        //Update Company Table with JobCount value
        //Save jobListingDomainModel
            
  }
```

Now the problem here is in case of simultaneous request to this API for example 2 request at once, same `JobCount` is shared among both the request hence for 2 new `JobListing`, I am getting the same `JobListingId`.

So by the time first API, updates the `JobCount` column in `Company` table, second api picks the same `JobCount` creating duplicate `JobListingId`.

How do I solve this problem so even If I have simultaneous request, both the request will always get a new JobCount from Company table guaranteeing a new JobListingId always?

### Update

I have already tried this:

```
Interlock.Increment
```

But still getting the duplicate JobListingId and also this is not a PrimaryKey in our table. This ID is we are manually creating and user friendly too because it is used by End users to search for their Job Listing. Hence can't use database AutoIncrement.

Comment: Is there a reason you are storing this value instead of calculating it?

Comment: @DavidG Actually tbh, I dont know why the value is stored and this is already implemented. Also, if we dont store the value and get the count of records from Company table, will it solve the problem?

Comment: Well if you always query the table using `SELECT COUNT...` then it will always be accurate.

Comment: @DavidG But since the records are saved at the end, the second request will still end up getting the same count right?

Comment: You can use a lock on that method, or you can maybe use the Retry pattern (Polly) to catch those exceptions (assuming it's a unique column) and re-execute after a certain number of milliseconds has elapsed. It depends on how often this case happens.

Comment: You need to use some sort of locking mechanism and transactions at the database level. You need to prevent the second client from selecting the jobcount value until after the first one has updated it and committed its transaction. There's not enough info to provide a complete answer here, but that's going to be the basis of it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Just to implement a manual ID creation, I should use Azure? Dont you think it would be a sort of overkill for such a simple scenario

Comment: @glenebob So I should place a lock on whole table or just that column JobListingId? Could you please provide some more info. I will really appreciate it

Comment: is there any particular reason why use id as a count number ? Guid seems like more viable solution. Let``s pretend that you have 100 concurrent request and 2 of them fails for some reason, and your logic with Id would still work - and we would have blank Id`s ... in case we need to have a count  (with 1 server)- might use come kind of in memory stored interlocked counter - it would only counts number for example successfully created JobListings. Count id is add not needed complexity, and that solution in case of multiple server would require for example Redis, is it worth it ?